# Equivalent Fractions

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find an example of two fraction symbols such that $p'/q'$ $\sim$ $p/q$ but $p'/q'$ is not of the form $mp/mq$ where $m\neq0$ and $m\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Note: $\sim$ is the symbol for equivalent fractions.

I have tried thinking about the equivalence class of $1/3$ but i am not sure how to proceed, may be i am not thinking in the right way. So please guide me, any help would be really appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try? Did you take a fraction of your choice and started going through other forms of writing it as a fraction?

Comment: Nothing wrong with $1/3$ --- just find *two* fractions equivalent to $1/3$ so you don't get either from the other by a simple cancellation.

Comment: Try $\frac{5}{15}\sim\frac{6}{18}$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT/COMMENT**

1. $\frac{1}{3}$ is  bad fraction to start with, maybe - mostly because of the $1$. If you want to start of a fraction, why not $\frac{2}{3}$?
2. Did you know that $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d} \implies ad = bc$?
3. Play around a bit.

Comment: Why do you say its a bad fraction and then recommend it? And yes i know ad = bc but as long as we are using integers, i don't know how to get the answer right now. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: @user: I'm sorry for recommending the same fraction. I meant to say $\frac{2}{3}$. I edited my answer.

Comment: do u have an example in yor mind?